# Java Capture all output from a process and log it to file

Tags: java, process

I'm trying log all output from an Application in java and for some reason it only capturing the first 2 lines i know the application outputs a lot more than this this is my code

```
logOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("WebAdmin.log"));

        ProcessBuilder procBuild = new ProcessBuilder(
            "java", "-Xmx1G", "-Xms512M", "-jar", "TekkitServer\\Tekkit.jar", "nogui", "-nojline"
        );
        server = procBuild.start();

        inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
        errorStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getErrorStream()));
        outputStream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(server.getOutputStream()));

        String line = "";

        while(!shutdown){
            while((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null){
                logOut.write(line+"\r\n");
                logOut.flush();
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            System.out.println("checking error stream");
            while((line = errorStream.readLine()) != null){
                logOut.write(line+"\r\n");
                logOut.flush();
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Stoped Reading");
        logOut.close();
        server.destroy();
```

I'm not even seeing "checking error stream" in my console.

Comment: The other lines might going to the errorstream!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a need for outer while, reading from the output stream blocks until there is some data available, and if the sub process ends you'll get a `null` and the inner while will break. Also you could use `ProcessBuilder`'s [redirectErrorStream(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream%28boolean%29) to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` so you will catch them both in only one loop.

Answer (score 1):

You must read the stdout and stderr streams in its own thread. Otherwise you will get all kinds of blocking situations (depending on operating system and output patterns).

If you merge the error stream with the output stream ([`redirectErrorStream(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream%28boolean%29)), you can get along with a single (additional) background thread. You can avoid this, when you use [`redirectOutput(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput%28java.io.File%29) (or inheritIO).